# Sending nested JSON object using HTTPie

Tags: json, httpie

I am trying to use HTTPie to parse to send some nested JSON object, but I can not find how. It is pretty clear how to send a JSON object but not a nested one such as

> { "user": {    "name": "john"
>       "age": 10 } }

Comment: A comma is missing in the json. It should be `{ "user": { "name": "john", "age": 10 } }`

Answer (score 145, accepted):

*Update for HTTPie 3.0 released in January 2022:*

There’s now built-in support for nested JSON using the HTTPie language:

```
$ http pie.dev/post \
  tool[name]=HTTPie \
  tool[about][homepage]=httpie.io \
  tool[about][mission]='Make APIs simple and intuitive' \
  tool[platforms][]=terminal \
  tool[platforms][]=desktop \
  tool[platforms][]=web \
  tool[platforms][]=mobile
```

```json
{
    "tool": {
        "name": "HTTPie",
        "about": {
            "mission": "Make APIs simple and intuitive",
            "homepage": "httpie.io"
        },
        "platforms": [
            "terminal",
            "desktop",
            "web",
            "mobile"
        ]
    }
}
```

You can learn more about nested JSON in the docs: https://httpie.io/docs/cli/nested-json

---

*Old answer for HTTPie older than 3.0:*

You can [pass the whole JSON via `stdin`](https://httpie.org/doc#redirected-input):

```
$ echo '{ "user": { "name": "john", "age": 10 } }' | http httpbin.org/post
```

Or [specify the raw JSON as value with `:=`](https://httpie.org/doc#json):

```
$ http httpbin.org/post user:='{"name": "john", "age": 10 }'
```

Comment: What about if name is actually a json object and not a table. Hence inside of user you name: {"id": "x", "fn":"xx"  }

Comment: What do you mean by "table"? In both of the examples above HTTPie sends the JSON object from you question.

Comment: Sorry by table i meant array

Comment: Both of the methods above allow you to specify arbitrary valid JSON data (object, array, boolean, etc.). See the links included in the answer.

Comment: In your example the second level is done trough an embedded Json file via bookmarks:=@bookmarks.json. For simplicity if hobbies:='["http", "pies"]' was not an array but an object "hobbies" : {"x": "x", "Y": y}. How would you have done it. My point is i try to use ":=" at the second level and it did not work whenever it was not an array.

Comment: The = and := assignments only allow you to assign non-nested properties. For anything more complex than a simple object it's better to use the first method.

Comment: Sorry if i am a bit slow to answer, but by first method you mean: using Echo ?

Comment: Yep, pipe or file redirect

Comment: @JuanSalvador the general idea is to pass the data via standard input (stdin). The specific syntax depends on the shell you use. The example above works with many Unix shell, but your shell might use a different syntax for the same thing.

Answer (score 72):

I like this way:

```
$ http PUT localhost:8080/user <<<'{ "user": { "name": "john", "age": 10 }}'
```

It is preferrable because it has the same prefix as the related commands, and so it is convenient to find the commands with `Ctrl+R` in bash:

```
$ http localhost:8080/user/all
$ http GET localhost:8080/user/all # the same as the previous
$ http DELETE localhost:8080/user/234
```

If you have [`fishshell`](https://fishshell.com/), which doesn't have [Here Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings), I can propose the following workaround:

```
~> function tmp; set f (mktemp); echo $argv > "$f"; echo $f; end
~> http POST localhost:8080/user < (tmp '{ "user": { "name": "john", "age": 10 }}')
```

Comment: @JuanSalvador we might do some workaround similar for fish I've done for the comment above.

Comment: My preference is to use fzf (shell tool), which lets ctrl+R do fuzzy find, so it can find old commands even if the searched text is in a different place in the old command :D

Answer (score 17):

Another approach mentioned in the httpie docs is using a [JSON file](https://httpie.io/docs/cli/raw-json); this has worked well for me for payloads that are more verbose and deeply nested.

```bash
http POST httpbin.org/post < post.json
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 (cmd.exe) the syntax is a *little* bit different due to quoting rules.  Properties/strings need to be surrounded by double quotes.

```
http -v post https://postman-echo.com/post address:="{""city"":""london""}"

POST /post HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: postman-echo.com
User-Agent: HTTPie/2.3.0
{
    "address": {
        "city": "london"
    }
}
```

You can also send the whole object using echo, and without double quoting.

```
echo {"address": {"city":"london"} } | http -v post https://postman-echo.com/post
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 3 ways to do it, all state in httpie doc,

1. https://httpie.io/docs/cli/non-string-json-fields

> For Non-string JSON fields use the :=

```
    http PUT pie.dev/put \
    name=John \                        # String (default)
    age:=29 \                          # Raw JSON — Number
    married:=false \                   # Raw JSON — Boolean
    hobbies:='["http", "pies"]' \      # Raw JSON — Array
    favorite:='{"tool": "HTTPie"}' \   # Raw JSON — Object
    bookmarks:=@files/data.json \      # Embed JSON file
    description=@files/text.txt        # Embed text file
```

2. https://httpie.io/docs/cli/raw-json

> For very complex JSON structures, it may be more convenient to pass it as raw request body, for example:

```
echo -n '{"hello": "world"}' | http POST pie.dev/post
// or
http POST pie.dev/post < files/data.json
```

3. https://httpie.io/docs/cli/nested-json (remember `=` for string and `:=` for non-string)

```
  http pie.dev/post \
  platform[name]=HTTPie \
  platform[about][mission]='Make APIs simple and intuitive' \
  platform[about][stars]:=54000 \
  ...
```

For your problem the easiest way is `user:='{ "name": "john" "age": 10 }'`