# Sending raw body with httpie in http-prompt

Tags: json, http, curl, httpie

HTTPie fills the request's body with stdin, so it's easy to send raw text or JSON with `echo '{...}' | http POST example.com` like here: [Sending nested JSON object using HTTPie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215565/sending-nested-json-object-using-httpie).

[`http-prompt`](http://docs.http-prompt.com/en/latest/user-guide.html) is a handy CLI interface for http and it allows setting body parameters like this:

```
> user=foo
```

or also in raw JSON:

```
> user:=foo
```

Which set the body to `{"user": "foo"}` upon sending.

But how can I send string `{"user": "foo"}` as the body directly?

1. As a text like `echo '{"user": "foo"}' | http POST http://example.com`
2. As a file like `curl --data '@/path/to/file' http://example.com`

Comment: Using `http-prompt` piping `> httpie post | sh -` but it fails in details.

Answer (score 2):

As of May 17, 2018: This cannot be done with http-prompt. There is an [open Github issue](https://github.com/eliangcs/http-prompt/issues/75) on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Such option has been added to HTTPie (`--raw`, https://httpie.io/docs/cli/request-data-via---raw) and will be made available for HTTP Prompt shortly.

Comment: This link seems to be defunct, but relevant docs can be found here: https://httpie.io/docs/cli/request-data-via---raw