# How to use HTTPie to send an un-named JSON array

Tags: httpie

I have an API I want to invoke that wants something like this to be POSTed in the body: `["foo","bar"]`

I have read the official docs and can't see how to do this, is it possible?

I have tried: `http --verbose PUT foo.org :='["foo","bar"]'`  but HTTPie still wants to turn that into a field of a JSON object, with no name, as in:

```json
{
    "": [
        "foo",
        "bar"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The shorthand syntax HTTPie offers doesn't support sending JSON values other than objects.
The easiest option here will be to pass the data via [redirected stdin](https://httpie.org/doc#redirected-input):

```bash
$ echo '["foo","bar"]' | http --verbose PUT foo.org
```

See also: [Sending nested JSON object using HTTPie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215565/sending-nested-json-object-using-httpie/37266537#37266537)