# How to send POST request for Nested JSON using HTTPie?

Tags: json, cmd, httpie

I want to send **POST** request using **HTTPie** from **Windows shell**

**JSON input Looks Like:**

```
{
    "name": "pub1",
    "email": "support@pub1.com",
    "address": {
        "city": "new york",
        "pincode": 12345
    }
}
```

**I have tried:**

```
http -v POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/publication/ name=pub1 email=support@pub1.com address:="{"city":"new york", "pincode":12345}"
```

**It Gives Following Error:**

```
http: error: "address:={city: new": Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

[image: httpie json error]

I did this using **Postman** and Its **Working**,
But I want to know How this can be done using **httpie?**

I also tried available solutions on SOF and GitHub, But Couldn't Figure out what is the problem.

Comment: Did you tried to use simple quotes outside httpie JSON args ? `address:='{"city":"Delhi", "pincode":24215}'`

Comment: Yes I tried with single quotes as well

Comment: Easiest way would be to put it in a file and do `http :8000/publication/ @file.json`, if that works for you.  Also, this question is purely about using `httpie` and has nothing to do with DRF, so maybe you can strip all that out and just keep the`httpie` part?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending nested JSON object using HTTPie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215565/sending-nested-json-object-using-httpie)

Comment: Thank You ! @AndrewBacker. I tried that solution in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215565/sending-nested-json-object-using-httpie] link, But its not working out. I tried with single as well as double quotes and every possible combination.

Comment: Try: `http -v :8000/publication/ name=pub1 email=support@pub1.com 'address:={"city":"new york", "pincode":12345}'`

Comment: I tried that too but didn't work..
@JakubRoztocil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows shell quoting rules are different, so you can't use `:='<json>'` with single quotes as all the osx/linux examples do, you need double quotes.

The error message that you get says "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes", but thats confusing since **it is** in double quotes to the naked eye.

Escaping the the double quotes inside the json literal will fix this.  You can do this by doubling up the quote character, as `""`.

`"city"` => `""city""`

```
http -v post https://postman-echo.com/post address:="{""city"":""london""}"

POST /post HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: postman-echo.com
User-Agent: HTTPie/2.3.0
{
    "address": {
        "city": "london"
    }
}
```

You can also use the echo trick to avoid all the quoting, if you prefer. This method is similar to using a file, so you specify the whole json document and **not** individual fields.

```
echo {"address": {"city":"london"} } | http -v post https://postman-echo.com/post
```